# How to commit a tracked file using git from the command prompt?

Tags: git, mingw

With zero knowlege of how git coding works, and zero knowlege of most of its syntax, I just spent the past two hours and thirty minutes trying to get the add command to work. Finally got it done; except now the ZebrasAss text file is not being committed.

The following [link](https://github.com/Merfrey/RDR2Rant) contains a copy and paste of the pre-course work stylized as a Red Dead Redemption 2 themed git project.

```
Administrator@DigitalStorm-PC MINGW64 ~
$ cd desktop

Administrator@DigitalStorm-PC MINGW64 ~/desktop
$ cd test

Administrator@DigitalStorm-PC MINGW64 ~/desktop/test
$ cd RDR2Rant

Administrator@DigitalStorm-PC MINGW64 ~/desktop/test/RDR2Rant (main)
$ ls
Micahass/  README.md  ZebrasAss.txt/

Administrator@DigitalStorm-PC MINGW64 ~/desktop/test/RDR2Rant (main)
$ git all .
git: 'all' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        pull

Administrator@DigitalStorm-PC MINGW64 ~/desktop/test/RDR2Rant (main)
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Administrator@DigitalStorm-PC MINGW64 ~/desktop/test/RDR2Rant (main)
$ git clone https://github.com/Merfrey/RDR2Rant.git
Cloning into 'RDR2Rant'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (6/6), done.

Administrator@DigitalStorm-PC MINGW64 ~/desktop/test/RDR2Rant (main)
$ git all .
git: 'all' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        pull

Administrator@DigitalStorm-PC MINGW64 ~/desktop/test/RDR2Rant (main)
$
```

I need any hints or advice as to why the tracked ZebrasAss is not being committed. Is it because I'm not understanding the vague instructions for my pre-course work?

Comment: git does not track directories.... so, that _empty_ directory you created.... git won't pat any attention to it unless you create some files inside and add them.

Comment: @eftshift0 I have a README file inside the RDR2Rant directory, along with the Zebrasass text file. Shouldn't git have tracked those when I tried to add them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think it is still not done? If you want to see changes in the remote repository, then you need to `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all files you can try

```
git add .
```

To check what has been changed you can use
Let’s say you add a new file to your project, a simple README file. If the file didn’t exist before, and you run git status, you see your untracked file like so:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    README

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

*git status* shows that you have some untracked files which you can add using *git add .*

Once you've added the file, you can commit using

```
git commit -m "your message"
```

Post that push your changes to remote using

```
git push
```

I would suggest creating a branch instead of working directly on *main*

Commands to create and push branch are as below[Don't forget to commit your changes to your branch:

```
$ git checkout -b branchB
$ git push origin branchB:branchB
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that 'touch' was a command to create a new file in github. Managed to solve my issue after creating a file using it inside the command line.